# Redis sorted set by string values

Tags: language-agnostic, redis, sorting

Suppose you have a hash 'users' whose entries map numeric IDs to JSON-encoded arrays, so, for instance, the integer 1 maps to the string {name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', occupation: 'plumber'}.

The numeric IDs of items in the hash are stored in various lists.  Thus, if 'foobar' is one of these lists, to retrieve the actual data from it I would run a simple Lua script (implementing a server-side join operation).  Or, as I've just learned, I could use something like

```
SORT foobar BY inexistent_key GET user:*
```

but that implies storing each user's data into a separate key which seems expensive (in my case I have many small collections so I want to take advantage of Redis compression of hashes).

The question is finally this: I need to keep these lists ordered alphabetically by, say, each user's surname, then by name.  What is the best way to achieve this, without changing too much the underlying data model (if possible)?

So far the best I could think of was using the SORT command together with the BY and STORE clauses, that is, running

```
SORT foobar BY surname:* STORE foobar
```

whenever the list is changed, but that way I'd need many keys.  If I could use a hash in the BY clause that would be the ideal solution, it seems to me.

If the fields I want to sort by were somehow limited (as in, just a couple hundred surnames) I could think of mapping strings to integers and use a Redis sorted set, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort by hash keys, without the complexity of Lua scripts, but you will have to duplicate the keys in your Json structure to Redis' hash keys.

The below example has the following structure:

**users** is a set with the user id's in query.

**user:X** is the Redis hash which contains the duplicated *name* / *surname* data.

**userdata:X** is your original users Json hash.

---

```
redis> hmset user:1 name First surname User
OK
redis> set userdata:1 "{occupation: 'Tester'}"
OK
redis> hmset user:2 name Last surname Violet
OK
redis> set userdata:2 "{occupation: 'Bookseller'}"
OK
redis> hmset user:3 name Middle surname Veredict
OK
redis> set userdata:3 "{occupation: 'Judge'}"
OK
redis> hmset user:4 name Ultimate surname Veredict
OK
redis> set userdata:4 "{occupation: 'Ultimate Judge'}"
OK
redis> sadd users 1
(integer) 1
redis> sadd users 2
(integer) 1
redis> sadd users 3
(integer) 1
redis> sadd users 4
(integer) 1
redis> sort users by user:*->surname get user:*->name get user:*->surname get userdata:* alpha
1) "First"
2) "User"
3) "{occupation: 'Tester'}"
4) "Middle"
5) "Veredict"
6) "{occupation: 'Judge'}"
7) "Ultimate"
8) "Veredict"
9) "{occupation: 'Ultimate Judge'}"
10) "Last"
11) "Violet"
12) "{occupation: 'Bookseller'}"
```

### Edit

I have overlooked that multiple `By` only consider the last clause. So you can't sort by more than one key in one command.

Also the `SORT` command used for lexicographic ordering now requires `alpha` modifier.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Niloct.  If I adopted your solution though, I'd have to add one hash per user, user:*, which is something I'm trying to avoid.  If I were to do this I'd also merge the userdata hash with the user:* hashes.  I'll run some tests to see the difference in memory usage between using many small hashes of JSON-encoded data (groups of users, in the example) and using one hash per item (one per user, in the example).

Comment: Well the difference in memory usage in my case is huge as expected.  Meanwhile I figured out that what I'd really like to be able to do is SORT foobar BY weights->* GET table->* but alas it doesn't seem to be possible...

Comment: Did you notice that multiple `BY` and `GET` are allowed ? You would have to issue one per field as in the example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe my comment wasn't clear enough. When I say that I'd like to be able to do SORT foobar BY weights->* what I mean is that the weight of the element X in foobar is what you'd find by issuing HGET weights X.  Thus you'd have just three keys: users (the hash which associates JSON data to IDs) weights (the hash that associates weights to IDs) and foobar (the set or list containing some of the IDs).  Instead if I follow your scheme, I'd need at least one key per element in the 'users' hash. Takes ten times more memory with my data (small hashes hence automatically zipped).

Comment: Understood. The star operator currently doesn't throw an error when issued after the `->` delimiter, but the results are inconsistent. Seems like you will have to make room for separated keys or go another route.

Comment: Yes! I noticed that no error is thrown using * after -> so I was hopeful at first, but it doesn't actually work as I'd like.  Today I came up with a little hack which I'm not sure is optimal but saves me a lot of memory, I'll post it below!

Comment: In case anyone runs into any headaches with this, this example does not work in 2.6. Your sort needs to add the ALPHA modifier like : "sort users by user:*->surname by user:*->name get user:*->name get user:*->surname get userdata:* ALPHA"

Answer (score 1):

In the end it seems to me that a way to approach my problem is to use the table.sort() function available in Lua.  In addition to the small hash 'users' and the small list of IDs 'foobar' I introduced another small hash, say 'users:sort-strings', where I store the strings by which I'd like to sort the IDs in 'foobar' (in the fictitious example a combination of surname and name). To sort 'foobar' I would then run the following Lua snippet in Redis, passing as keys 'foobar', 'users:sort-strings' and 'foobar:tmp' (a temporary key).

```
local lst = redis.call('LRANGE', KEYS[1], 0, -1)
local sort_function = function (id0, id1)
   local s0 = redis.call('HGET', KEYS[2], id0)
   local s1 = redis.call('HGET', KEYS[2], id1)
   return (s0 < s1)
end
table.sort(lst, sort_function)
for key, value in ipairs(lst) do
   redis.call('RPUSH', KEYS[3], value)
end
redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1])
redis.call('RENAME', KEYS[3], KEYS[1])
```

Comment: Interesting! How does it compare in resources comsumption ? Is it fast ?